# Revert/Reload all open files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to figure this out, and cannot determine if it is possible or not.

Essentially, I commonly work with a VSCode window containing many files located on an external network drive (CIFS mount in Linux). When these files are changed "on-disk", they do not update in the editor until I switch focus to each file by changing the active editor tab. This means I have to switch tabs, wait for the update to process, and then repeat for all open tabs (could be 10 or 20 tabs).

Is there anyway to force all open editors to refresh or revert at once? That would ease my workflow a lot for examining differences between these open files on the fly. There's a command to "Revert File", but that only works on the open file, rather than all currently-opened ones. I've looked in the settings and browsed for an extension, but I can't find anything to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can try to map the external network drive to local disk and give appropriate permission for read and write restriction.

If your computer has firewall or anti virus installed, then you must exclude vs access restriction from fw/av inspection.

Otherwise you can also improve your network adapter performance, associate to buffers, throughput, packet latency, etc.

Alternatively, you can use any source control, so your codes could be persist locally and could be synchronized from/to source control server.

Hope this could helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is helpful to me, as I already have the network drive mounted locally, and my question isn't about latency/source control. I'm updating files on the remote share, and viewing them in VS Code. I want VS Code to reload them on my command, rather than when I manually browse to each editor's tab.